# Comparing list of values associated with a key in a dictionary to the values associated all other keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is the code i wrote to compare the list of values associated with each key to all other keys in the dictionary... But it is taking a hell lot of time more some 10000 records in the csv file..Can any body help to optimize the code to execute in minimal time.. Don't worry about the external function call,it works fine.

```
import csv
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]
with open(file, 'rU') as inf:
    csvreader=csv.DictReader(inf,delimiter=',')
    result={}
    temp = []
#Creating Dict
    for r in csvreader:
        name=[]
        name.append(r['FIRST_NAME'])
        name.append(r['LAST_NAME'])
        name.append(r['ID'])
        result.setdefault(r['GROUP_KEY'],[]).append(name) 

#Processing the Dict

for key1 in result.keys():
    temp.append(key1)
    for key2 in result.keys():
        if key1 != key2 and key2 not in ex:
            for v1 in result[key1]:
                for v2 in result[key2]:
                    score=name_match_score(v1,'',v2,'')[0] ####calling external function
                    if score > 0.90:
                        print v1[2],v2[2],score
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help. The goal is to reduce the number of raw calculations done in `name_match_score` by skipping redundant calculations and by caching calculations performed.

First, make your dictionary store a defaultdict of lists of tuples. Tuples are immutable so they can be used as keys in sets and dicts below.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import sys

file = sys.argv[1]
with open(file, 'rU') as inf:
    csvreader=csv.DictReader(inf, delimiter=',')
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for r in csvreader:
        name = (r['FIRST_NAME'], r['LAST_NAME'], r['ID'])
        result[r['GROUP_KEY']].append(name)
```

Then, sort your keys to ensure you evaluate a pair of keys only once.

```
keys = sorted(result)
for i, key1 in enumerate(keys):
    for key2 in keys[i+1:]:
```

And order `v1` and `v2` so that they form a unique key. This will help with caching.

```
        for v1 in result[key1]:
            for v2 in result[key2]:
                v1, v2 = (min(v1, v2), max(v1, v2))
                score=name_match_score(v1, v2)[0] ####calling external function
                if score > 0.90:
                    print v1[2],v2[2],score
```

Then use a [memoizing decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) to cache calculations:

```
class memoized(object):
    '''Decorator. Caches a function's return value each time it is called.
    If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned
    (not reevaluated).
    '''
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if not isinstance(args, collections.Hashable):
            # uncacheable. a list, for instance.
            # better to not cache than blow up.
            return self.func(*args)
        if args in self.cache:
            return self.cache[args]
        else:
            value = self.func(*args)
            self.cache[args] = value
            return value
    def __repr__(self):
        '''Return the function's docstring.'''
        return self.func.__doc__
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        '''Support instance methods.'''
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)
```

And change `name_match_score` to use the decorator:

```
@memoized
def name_match_score(v1, v2):
    # Whatever this does
    return (0.75, )
```

This should minimize the number of raw calculations inside `name_match_score` that you do.

Comment: File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    if vkey not in vseen:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Doesn't help...takes a lot more time, since it checks on sets again and again.